# How do I use multiple databases with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I need two or more than two connections in my web application using jpa

Comment: are you talking about multiple data sources? Because DB connections and data sources are quite different terms.

Comment: two data sources like both will be a oracle database but the crdentials sid and all will be different for the two data sources

Answer (score 12):

To use different data sources, add multiple persistence units (say, `source-1` and `source-2` in `persistence.xml` and create multiple `EntityManagerFactory`es by name):

```
EntityManagerFactory emf1 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("source-1");
EntityManagerFactory emf2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("source-2");
```

or, if you're working on Spring or Java EE application server, inject them by name also:

```
@PersistenceUnit(name = "source-1")
EntityManagerFactory emf1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "source-2") // as an option
EntityManager em2;
```

`persistence.xml` will thus look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="source-1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <!-- source-1 properties here -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="source-2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <!-- source-2 properties here -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Example of how to configure persistence unit, create `EntityManager` to manage entities and execute queries can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html).

Comment: Can you please share a example of such as i m new to this concept and not able to decide what to do

Comment: it is telling muliplt persistence unit defined only the first persistence unit will be identified

Comment: @RahulSingh Hibernate will define all persistence units listed in `persistence.xml`, tested many times. Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356152/two-persistence-unit-in-one-persistence-xml

Answer (score -5):

For single datasource jpa will use multiple connections internally.So you don't need to do anything.

Comment: The question is not about connections to the same database,but to multiple different DBs. Though, I understand that the wording in the question is confusing