# JPA Entity mapping to specific table

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

My Project has 2 mysql databases. I have written JPA's for them. But while running it gives error.

Example:
Database: One Table: Table1
Database: Two Table Table2

While creating entity manager for database "One" it says "Table2" missing & While creating entity manager for database "Two" it says "Table1" missing.

Comment: Post the error message dude so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In persistence.xml

Added `<class>org.x.y.JPA's</class>` (JPA's/Classes that are referring to that persistence unit/database)  & `<exclude-unlisted-classes> true </exclude-unlisted-classes>`
before

```
<properties> 
...
..
..
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth JPA you declare Persistence Unit which tells the code which data base to look at, since you have two separate databases, you will have to have multiple Persistence Units.

Take a look at the other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257543/how-do-i-use-multiple-databases-with-jpa?noredirect=1&lq=1) on SO for hints on how to progress.

Comment: Thanks dubes ... but found a work around with the existing thing...posted below