# can we use one entity manager for multiple databases in hibernate and if yes please how can i do this with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Can we  use one entity manager for multiple databases in `hibernate`?

If yes please how can I do this with `Spring MVC`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use one entity manager.  see post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257543/how-do-i-use-multiple-databases-with-jpa

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple databases" ? multiple schema in the same database server? I don't see what Spring MVC has got to do with that at all ... this is JPA and nothing else

Comment: yes in the same database  server, with Spring i can use @primary